# install error wubi 12.10 rev273

Tags: system-installation, wubi

Keep getting this error when installing wubi 12.10 rev273

11-09 14:16 ERROR  TaskList: Error executing command

> > command=C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe /set {31400a42-f78f-11e0-9f68-e8757c793044} device partition=F:
> >     retval=1
> >     stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.

The request is not supported.

> > stdout=
> >     Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in **call**
> >       File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 697, in modify_bcd
> >       File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 66, in run_command
> >     Exception: Error executing command
> >     command=C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe /set {31400a42-f78f-11e0-9f68-e8757c793044} device partition=F:
> >     retval=1
> >     stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.

The request is not supported.

Am trying to install in F drive

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem, and I think I finally found the answer!

Problem: You might be running Windows on a dynamic disk. Windows does this thing where it converts the disk in its proprietory dynamic format, which linux cannot read.

You can find out if your disk is dynamic or not, by right clicking on "My Computer" -> Manage -> Storage -> Disk Management. See if your disk is "Basic" or "Dynamic".

It should look something like this.:

[image: It should look something like this.]

Solution:

1. Download the [EaseUS partition tool](http://www.partition-tool.com/) and install it.
2. Backup all your data!
3. Find your disk on it, right click, and then "Convert to Basic".

After this, move Wubi to the same directory as your downloaded ISO file and run it (or if you have not downloaded the iso file, then just run it!)

**WARNING**: I did not face any problem with data losses during the dynamic to basic conversion process, but I imagine there is a significant risk of you losing all or some data. Please BACKUP before you attempt to convert it!